# ORA-12170: TNS: Se agotó el tiempo de espera de conexión CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

Hola amigos tengo este error. estoy en un Ubuntu 18.04

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Filename: models/M_Oracle.php

Line Number: 11
```

mi conexion es esta

```
public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      echo "<h1>On the constructor</h1><br>";
      $this->db_oracle = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip_del_servidor)(PORT=1521)))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=puvidb)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))';
      $this->conexion = oci_connect("my_user", "my_password", $this->db_oracle,"AL32UTF8");
      if (!$this->conexion) {
         $m = oci_error();
         trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
     }
   }
```

Ya instale los driver de oci8 no se si estan bien instalados la verdad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, espero a nadie le ocurre, el error no esta en el codigo al aprecer mi codigo era correcto. Pero hay un detalle y es que mi aplicacion esta en un servidor Linux(Ubuntu18.04) y la BD esta en otro servidor linux(Ubuntu18.04) osea estan separados; ahora yo estaba intentado conectarme por medio de la ip=(ip_publica) lo que ocurria es que el sevidor al tener que usar la ip publica pues no podia conectarse ya que estos dos servidores estan conectados localmente la solucion a esto es conectarme por medio de la ip=(ip_privada).

**Ahora recomiendo para que prueben**
Instalen en sus servidores Ubuntu SQLPLus para que puedan conectarse a BD oracle y usen este comando.
sqlplus Usuario/Contraseña_Del_Usuario@Aqui_va_la_ip_de_la_BD:1521/Aqui_va_EL_SID
Ejemplo:  `sqlplus system/contraseña@localhost:1521/orcl`
Es importante que prueben todas las ip posibles si ven que nos les conecta.
Final de la solución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]